# record video & audio to mp4 file on windows pc

Tags: c++

I have received video packets(h264) and audio packets(aac) from network(somewhere) separately. And i can get the ntptime of every packet(a or v).
now I want write them to a mp4 file in 25 fps, how can l do?

I have tried to do it using ffmpeg, but failed. please help me, thanks.

Comment: And the video packets maybe coming discontinuously, such as, video1 timestamp 1s, video2 timestamp 4s.

Comment: If You describe Your problems with the ffmpeg, You may get help. The question in current form is too broad.